# When cant a object be added to an object

Tags: javascript, json

Trying to add a value to a object. The object was generated from the start by a database request, containing a number of entires. A sample entry (say number 0) looks as follows:

```
{ _id: 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d,
  fulltext: 'Finance',
  alias: 'Finance',
  level: 0,
  fullurl: 'http://v-ghost.port0.org:808/dbfswiki/index.php/FMP',
  __v: 0,
  _parrent: [] 
}
```

Now I want to add an additional array to this object. An empty structure where there will be a number of other listings. I started by using `.push`, but the object does not have a `push` function. This one has done a few rounds, so latest version below:

The structure I do want is:

```
    { _id: 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d,
      fulltext: 'Finance',
      alias: 'Finance',
      level: 0,
      fullurl: 'http://v-ghost.port0.org:808/dbfswiki/index.php/FMP',
      __v: 0,
      _parrent: [] 
      childs: [] 
}
```

I am not putting anything into childs at this point *(childs because children seems to reserved, and while it might work, don't really want to try changing it when the code is already broken)*, basically just adding an empty slot to put similar objects into as part of later processing.
**Really weird**
Changed the code as follows:
    console.log ("Root record now " + rootRecord);
    rootRecord.childs = 1;
    console.log("Alias is " + rootRecord.alias);
    console.log("Child is " + rootRecord.childs);
    console.log("The complete structure is: \n"+rootRecord)

And I get the following output

```
Alias is Finance
Child is 1
The complete structure is: 
{ _id: 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d,
  fulltext: 'Finance',
  alias: 'Finance',
  level: 0,
  fullurl: 'http://v-ghost.port0.org:808/dbfswiki/index.php/FMP',
  __v: 0,
  _parrent: [] }
```

So I can read rootRecord.childs, but its not listed, its almost as it is a "hidden" variable somehow.

**The offending code**

```
                console.log("Creating root structure");
                var roots = docs[doc];
                console.log("Root from docs: \n" + docs[doc])
                console.log("Sealed: " + Object.isSealed(docs[doc]));
                console.log("Frozen " + + Object.isFrozen(docs[doc]));
                console.log("Is Extendable: " + isExtendable(docs[doc]));
                console.log("Is Extensible(es6): " + Object.isExtensible(docs[doc]));
                for (var root in docs[doc]){
                    var rootRecord = docs[doc][root];
                    console.log ("Root record now " + rootRecord);
                    rootRecord.childs = [];
                    console.log("Now its " + rootRecord);
                    returnStructure.push(rootRecord);
                    console.log("returnStructure is now:\n" + returnStructure);
                    console.log("And first id is " + returnStructure[0]['_id'])

                }
```

Gives the following output:

```
Creating root structure
Root from docs: 
{ _id: 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d,
  fulltext: 'Finance',
  alias: 'Finance',
  level: 0,
  fullurl: 'http://v-ghost.port0.org:808/dbfswiki/index.php/FMP',
  __v: 0,
  _parrent: [] }
Sealed: false
Frozen 0
Is Extendable: true
Is Extensible(es6): true
Root record now { _id: 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d,
  fulltext: 'Finance',
  alias: 'Finance',
  level: 0,
  fullurl: 'http://v-ghost.port0.org:808/dbfswiki/index.php/FMP',
  __v: 0,
  _parrent: [] }
Now its { _id: 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d,
  fulltext: 'Finance',
  alias: 'Finance',
  level: 0,
  fullurl: 'http://v-ghost.port0.org:808/dbfswiki/index.php/FMP',
  __v: 0,
  _parrent: [] }
returnStructure is now:
{ _id: 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d,
  fulltext: 'Finance',
  alias: 'Finance',
  level: 0,
  fullurl: 'http://v-ghost.port0.org:808/dbfswiki/index.php/FMP',
  __v: 0,
  _parrent: [] }
And first id is 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d
```

**Full source code**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var async = require('async');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ResourceProfiles');
//var ObjectId = require('mongoose').ObjectID;
var isExtendable = require('is-extendable');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;


var Profile = mongoose.model('Profile', {
    alias: String,
    img: String,
    name: String,
    summary: String,
    CV: String,
    keys: String,
    avail: String,
    agent: String,
    __v: {type: Number, select: false},
    comp: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    comn: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    intp: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    intn: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    orgp: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    orgn: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    swep: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    swen: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    pssp: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    pssn: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    pep: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    pen: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    gtemp: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    gtemn: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});

var Skill = mongoose.model('Skill', {
    alias: String,
    fulltext: {
        type: String
        , required: true
        , unique: true
    },
    fullurl: String,
    level: Number,
    _parrent: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Skill'}],

})


    console.log("Lets see if we can't figure out this one once and for all");
    var queries= [];
    var maxLevels = 1;
    [0,1,2,3,4].forEach(function(i){
        console.log("Looking for "+ i)
        queries.push(function (cb) {
            console.log("Seaching for "+ i)
            Skill.find({level: i}).exec(function (err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    throw cb(err);
                }

                // do some stuff with docs & pass or directly pass it
                cb(null, docs);
            });
        });
    })
    console.log("All requests generated");
    async.parallel(queries, function(err, docs) {
        // if any query fails
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var returnStructure = [];
        console.log("This is what we got back")
        for (var doc in docs){
                if ( docs[doc].length === 0 ){
                    console.log("No entries in level " + doc)
                } else {
                    console.log("Processing " + docs[doc].length + " for level " + doc)
                    if ( doc === "0" ) {
                        console.log("Creating root structure");
                        var roots = docs[doc];
                        console.log("Root from docs: \n" + docs[doc])
                        console.log("Sealed: " + Object.isSealed(docs[doc]));
                        console.log("Frozen " + + Object.isFrozen(docs[doc]));
                        console.log("Is Extendable: " + isExtendable(docs[doc]));
                        console.log("Is Extensible(es6): " + Object.isExtensible(docs[doc]));
                        for (var root in docs[doc]){
                            var rootRecord = docs[doc][root];
                            console.log ("Root record now " + rootRecord);
                            rootRecord.childs = [];
                            console.log("Now its " + rootRecord);
                            returnStructure.push(rootRecord);
                            console.log("returnStructure is now:\n" + returnStructure);
                            console.log("And first id is " + returnStructure[0]['_id'])

                        }
                    /*} else if ( doc === "1"){
                        var skills = docs[doc];
                        for (var skill in skills){
                            console.log("Need to find " + skills[skill].alias + " parrent " + skills[skill]._parrent);
                            for (var root in returnStructure) {
                                if ( returnStructure[root]["_id"].toString() === skills[skill]["_parrent"].toString()){
                                    console.log("Found parrent " + returnStructure[root].alias);
                                    var newSkill = [];
                                    var childs =  { childs: {}};
                                    newSkill.push(skills[skill]);
                                    newSkill.push(childs);
                                    console.log("This is it " + returnStructure);
                                    returnStructure[root].childs.push(newSkill);
                                }
                            }
                            console.log(returnStructure);
                        }
                    } else if ( doc === "2"){
                        var skills = docs[doc];
                        for (var skill in skills){
                            console.log("Need to find " + skills[skill].alias + " parrent " + skills[skill]._parrent);
                            for (var root in returnStructure){
                                //var parrents= returnStructure[root].childs;
                                for (var parrent in returnStructure[root].childs){
                                    console.log("Lets compare \n" + returnStructure[root].childs[parrent]._id + "\n" + skills[skill]._parrent);
                                    if(  returnStructure[root].childs[parrent]._id.toString() === skills[skill]["_parrent"].toString() ){
                                        console.log("Hello found " + returnStructure[root].childs[parrent].childs);
                                        skills[skill].childs = [];
                                        console.log(skills[skill])
                                        returnStructure[root].childs[parrent].childs.push(skills[skill])

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        */
                    }

            //    }

            }


        }

    })
```

Comment: You show your object before the data insertion. Please also show the object in the desired state after the insertion - it is not very easy to understand exactly what you want from your description. But in general, with objects, you would assign new attributes using `root.newAttribute = newValue`.

Comment: I don’t get what `_id` is. It’s neither a valid number nor string nor variable name.

Comment: To answer the question from the title: you can’t add to an object that is frozen, sealed or non-extensible.

Comment: Xufox, _id is the id from the database, potentially why it would be frozen. Will try to see if that will help me.

Comment: can i "unfreeze" an object, or find out if it is frozen, sealed or non-extensible.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with the object but not an array, you should simply assign this value:

```
var obj = {
   a: 1,
   b: "str"
};
obj.c = 3; // not obj.push(3); or whatever else
```

Your example is pretty not clear. As I understand, you want to assign an array of objects in `roots` to `returnStructure`. Otherwise, you simply rewrite values in your object.

If you do this:

```
returnStructure.childs = roots; // not children, childS, really? :)
```

Then, your object will look like this:

```
{ 
    _id: '55c8a069cca746f65c98369d',
    fulltext: 'Finance',
    alias: 'Finance',
    level: 0,
    fullurl: 'http://127.0.0.1/wiki/index.php/FMP',
    __v: 0,
    _parrent: [],
    childs: [
        {"all": "objects"},
        {"from": "roots"},
        {"whatever": "they are"}
    ]
}
```

If I am wrong, please, make clarifications and add some code - what is your `roots` objects; what is `returnStructure` and how should it look like after assignment.

**Update:**
In any other case, that's how you create an empty array as a part of an object:

```
returnStructure.childs = [];
```

Then, you can always add any objects to it like this:

```
returnStructure.childs.push(obj);
returnStructure.childs.push(1);
```

Comment: Funnily enough, your first suggestion is what I tried initially Yeldar

Comment: Your code would generate a structure with roots as child to the first returnStructure array, I need to generate an empty array to push new ones into (It's for a tree structure). (And yes, selected childs because the IDE highlighted children as a reserved word, so thought I would change it just in case that was causing the issue).

Comment: Sadly enough it did not. Have moved the code to do the following. Copy roots[root] to new object called newRoot (just in case). Set newRoot.childs to {}. (Or anyhing, its like it just dont want to change)`                             var cuRoot = [];
                            cuRoot=roots[root];
                            cuRoot.childs = []; `

Comment: Seems like part of the problem is that there is a lot of other stuff in the object, and I am not certain what has to be there or not.

Comment: FYI, the `childs` structure you show is not valid Javascript and would not work.  You can't have an object like this: `{"all objects"}`.  You must have both property name and value.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for clarification! I wasn't going to make it a proper JS - more like comment. But you are right - it may be confusing. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your current data structure:

```
var data = { _id: 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d,
  fulltext: 'Finance',
  alias: 'Finance',
  level: 0,
  fullurl: 'http://v-ghost.port0.org:808/dbfswiki/index.php/FMP',
  __v: 0,
  _parrent: [] 
}
```

And, you just want to add the `childs` property to it with an empty array, then you can just assign that new property to the object.

```
data.childs = [];
```

That will give you this result:

```
{ _id: 55c8a069cca746f65c98369d,
  fulltext: 'Finance',
  alias: 'Finance',
  level: 0,
  fullurl: 'http://v-ghost.port0.org:808/dbfswiki/index.php/FMP',
  __v: 0,
  _parrent: [], 
  childs: []
}
```

If you then want to add some items to the `childs` array, you can do this:

```
data.childs.push("hello");
data.childs.push("goodbye");
```

Or, if you want to push an object into the array instead of the above strings, you could do this:

```
data.childs.push({greeting: "hellow"});
```

---

Object properties are just directly assigned as in `data.childs = []`.  If the property does not exist, it will be created and given this initial value.  If the property already exists, its value will be changed.

`.push()` is used to add an item onto the end of an array that already exists so you can't use `.push()` on an object or on a property that doesn't yet have an array in it.

Comment: That is the very first thing I tried, but for some reason it just will not allow me to do it that way.  Trying to figure out why it wouldn't work that way

Comment: @vrghost - what I've shown works.  If it's not working for you, then there is something else going on in your code that you have not shown us.  If you want us to help you with that, you will have to show more of your code context so we can see what else is going wrong.  It may also help if you see what script errors might be showing in the debug console when you try this.

Comment: So, your code works, and doesn't. See my edit above (where it goes really weird). So I can read rootRecord, but its not listed...

Answer (score 0):

So after much faffing about, I managed to figure out where I was going wrong, and it was in the data object rather than the code. 
So the data in `docs[doc]` is a object, or a set of objects in a object, or something else funny.

- It reacted as a object at times (fore example if you asked for docs[doc].alias).
- If you just asked what was in it (as in console.log(docs[doc]) it returned something that looked like a JSON object *(should have realised at this time that something was up, it should have returned [Object Object])*
- If you tried to change it or add anything, thats when problems started.

In this case, I ran a listing of the object it self (`for (var id in docs[doc]){console.log("ID: "+id+" data:\n " + docs[doc][id])}` This returned a lot of stuff, including a function called toJSON(). Guess what, changing the line to `var rootRecord = docs[doc][id].toJSON();` Sorted the problem.

Sorry if I missed something REALLY obvious, but pretty certain this isn't the normal behaviour. Think it may be async or mongoose that added the weird structures.